# GA4 Page Views & Titles Screen Doesn't Match other reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

This question is for Google GA4 Analytics -

I have this data stream that may drive me insane. You see here under the Engagement < Overview you can see that blog entries are being viewed and can see their titles. I know for a fact these pages have been visited 100s of times. But when I use the Overview or Engagement < Pages and Screens - it shows the Views as 0. But the pages are being and have been viewed numerous times. See the red highlighted photos I have attached so you can see just one page on my site that shows it has users but then no views. This has been going on forever and I cannot for the life of me get my Pages and Screens to show the views as anything other than zero.

This is a WordPress site and has WooCommerce installed and the WooCommerce analytics plugin with the G-Tag associated. It is tracking the home page of the site and all the WooCommerce pages, but NOTHING ELSE under page views but you can see the page titles if you go under user engagement and then page titles, what gives?

[image]

[image]